# make sure my auth request (axios) always runs first (react-native)

Tags: react-native

Stack:

- react-native@0.72.3
- react-navigation@6.1.7
- axios@1.4.0
- 

I have an authentication context with a fetchSession function (axios request). This request should run first when the app opens, because this fetches an access token which is used in subsequent requests.

Normal situation:
I have a feed screen (FeedScreen) with an axios request to the server which fetches feed items. This request uses the access token. I log which requests are made. When I open the app, I see in the console that the fetchSession()-request is done first, and after that the fetchFeed()-request. So this works.

When you open the app normally, you see the feed-screen first, and everything works as expected.

I also have an item screen (ItemScreen). This screen has the details of an item, and also has a request (fetchItem()). This request also uses the access token.

I'm using react-navigation for deeplinking, so through an url, you can open the app directly to a feed item. My deeplinking object looks like this:

```
const prefixes = ["myapp://" ,"https://myapp.com"];
const config = {
    screens: {
        FeedStack: {
            screens: {
                ItemScreen: {
                    path: 'item/:itemId'
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So when you navigate to https://myapp.com/item/1 on mobile devices, you can open the app directly on ItemScreen for item ID 1.  This works as expected, but something strange happens.

In this case: the fetchItem()-request **is made before the fetchSession()-request**. This doesn't happen when opening the app in a normal way.

I have a custom axios-object with a request and response handler. This is used when the access token invalidates, to request a new one and to re-run the request. This works. But now, the access token isn't invalidated yet, it's just not there.

A possible solution is to create a isAuthenticated-state in the fetchSession()-request and set it to "true" when the session is fetched, and add this ass a dependecy for the useEffect function for fetchItem(). This will probably work, but I just don't get why in the normal case, the fetchSession()-request is ran first, and when in the linking state, the fetchSession()-request is ran last.

I tried swapping the FeedScreen with the ItemScreen (with a fixed ID) as the startup screen. In that case, the fetchSession()-request is also ran first. So I think it's definitely something with the linking behaviour.

**Edit:**

I created this custom hook: useAuthEffect()

```
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {useAuthentication} from 'contexts/AuthenticationContext';
import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';

export default useAuthEffect = (fnc, deps) => {
  const {isAuthenticated} = useAuthentication();

  return useEffect(() => {
    if (isEqual(isAuthenticated, true)) {
      fnc();
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated, ...deps]);
};
```

This seems to work, but I'm a react native beginner: I have no idea if this is the ideal solution or not.